# Bizarre integer behavior in cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm running into a strange issue with some integer manipulation in cython. When I compile this cython code ...

test.pyx

```
from libc.math cimport abs

cdef int c = 2047
cdef int b = 1009
print('%d'%(-(abs(b)&c)))
```

...like this

```
#!python
from subprocess import check_output

CFLAGS = check_output('python-config --cflags'.split()).decode('utf-8').strip()
LDFLAGS = check_output('python-config --ldflags'.split()).decode('utf-8').strip()

check_output('cython test.pyx'.split())

compile_call = ('clang -c test.c %s'%(CFLAGS)).split()
check_output(compile_call)

link_call = ('clang test.o -o test.so -shared %s'%(LDFLAGS)).split()
check_output(link_call)

import test
```

...I get `2130706744`, but the right answer is `-1009`.

Comment: Strange. Something appears to be treated as unsigned. The C `abs` returns a signed int...

Comment: The code in C with all of the python related stuff removed is showing `-1009`. https://ideone.com/aOyfLu

Comment: Not familiar with cython, but it looks like it is producing an intermediate C source? Can we look at it?

Comment: Yeah, looking at `test.c` would be quite helpful for debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this might be a bug in Cython. The relevant line in `test.c` is

```
__pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_unsigned_int((-(__pyx_t_1 & __pyx_v_4test_c)));
```

Clearly interpreting our number as unsigned gives a wrong answer. However if I remove the `abs` call, then I get

```
__pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_int((-(__pyx_v_4test_b & __pyx_v_4test_c)));
```

and the result is correct. If I add a cast to int like `print('%d'%(-(<int>abs(b)&c)))` then I also get the right answer.

Cross posted to the [Cython github page](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1837)

**Update:** Here is the response to my github issue:

> Basically, a signed int is not large enough to hold abs(-MAX_INT-1),
>   so the result was changed to return an unsigned value. On the other
>   hand, I agree that using an unsigned value is quite confusing as well,
>   especially as promotion of equally ranked integers is to the unsigned
>   type so it's contagious. Unclear what the best course of action is
>   here...

Comment: Looking through the Cython source, I can confirm the existence of a [declaration of `abs`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/a0bbb940c847dfe92cac446c8784c34c28c92836/Cython/Includes/libc/stdlib.pxd#L51) from the C stdlib with the correct return type, but also [other `abs` routines](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/c4ba71f488535cab6ea78c3e56e0a977d9a0f853/Cython/Utility/Builtins.c#L230) that return unsigned types.

Comment: The ones with unsigned return types appear to be used in the Cython compiler for [calling the builtin `abs` on C ints](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/c4ba71f488535cab6ea78c3e56e0a977d9a0f853/Cython/Compiler/Builtin.py#L99); this may be overriding your explicit `cimport`, although I feel like it shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think Cython should have ever used an unsigned return type for the built-in `abs`.

Comment: So why is the result 2130706744? I would expect 4294966287 (2**32 - 1009).